# Strange Behaviour with signalR and IE10 and fiddler

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, signalr

I have a signalR sample working project. When I run it in IE10, I can see that the foreverframe mechanism is used to establish asynchronous communication between the server and the client. I saw this using the IE10 developer tools by pressing F12.

When I see the same client IE10 in fiddler and press refresh(or start a new client in IE10) i notice that long polling is being used instead.

When I close fiddler and check again in IE, I notice the foreverframe.

This is strange. Anyone out there who knows why this is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On fiddler, you need to set it in "Steam" mode ( click the "Stream" button to enable it) for foreverframe and serverSentEvents transports. Could you try again? if it still repro, please let us know the logging in IE / F12 developer tools /console.